# How to pad an array with zeros?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

```
fn main() {
    let arr: [u8;8] = [97, 112, 112, 108, 101];
    println!("Len is {}",arr.len());
    println!("Elements are {:?}",arr);
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:2:23
  |
2 |     let arr: [u8;8] = [97, 112, 112, 108, 101];
  |              ------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of 8 elements, found one with 5 elements
  |              |
  |              expected due to this
```

Is there any way to pad the remaining elements with 0's? Something like:

```
let arr: [u8;8] = [97, 112, 112, 108, 101].something();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, you can use const generics to write a dedicated method.

```rust
fn pad_zeroes<const A: usize, const B: usize>(arr: [u8; A]) -> [u8; B] {
    assert!(B >= A); //just for a nicer error message, adding #[track_caller] to the function may also be desirable
    let mut b = [0; B];
    b[..A].copy_from_slice(&arr);
    b
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=46f973770eb78b8681bfea297784522b)

Comment: Nice and simple solution.

Comment: Thanks mate. Simple solution easy to understand for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [concat_arrays](https://docs.rs/concat-arrays/0.1.2/concat_arrays/macro.concat_arrays.html) macro for it:

```
use concat_arrays::concat_arrays;

fn main() {
    let arr: [u8; 8] = concat_arrays!([97, 112, 112, 108, 101], [0; 3]);
    println!("{:?}", arr);
}
```

I don't think it's possible to do without external dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

You could start with zeros and set the initial values afterwards. This requires `arr` to be `mut` though.

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr: [u8;8] = [0;8];
    let init = [97, 112, 112, 108, 101];
    arr[..init.len()].copy_from_slice(&init);

    println!("Len is {}",arr.len());
    println!("Elements are {:?}",arr);
}
```

Link to [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=34b621994bca7c028d275d67b5a6b46e)